# How can I save values generated by a Manipulate expression to a CSV file?

Tags: manipulate, export, output-formatting

I have trouble generating and saving data from a manipulation that determines  parameters. Can someone please help me?

```
Manipulate[Plot[{func,x}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

I want to save `x` and `func` results.

Comment: It is really difficult to give any kind of answer to this question because 1) Manipulate[Plot[{func,x}, {x, 0, 3}] is syntactically and semantically invalid. 2) You do not give specifications of what each CSV file record should contain

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `Manipulate` to set a parameter, then exporting data.
Using the `func` example from Xminer's answer:

```
func[a_, x_] := Sin[a x]
```

The following `Manipulate` lets you set `a` between 1 and 10, shows the plot of `Sin[a x]`, and defines a table `data` containing samples from `func[a,x]`.

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   "a = " <> ToString[a],
   Plot[func[a, x], {x, 1, 10}],
   data = Table[{a, x, func[a, x]}, {x, 1, 10, .1}];
   }]
 , {a, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

The variable `data` contains lists of the form `{a, x, func[a,x]}`, for example

```
data // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then it's just a matter of exporting.

```
Export["filename.csv", data]
```

This generates a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

Which can then be used in Excel or imported into Mathematica.